# Is this press fitting crimp mangled?

Tags: plumbing, tools

So far I've used a manual crimping tool only on a few lead-free stop-valves, where I bought press-style valves because of the possibility of overheating the valve when soldering and damaging the seals.

None of my crimps and none of those I've seen look like the one I have highlighted in this photo, which is taken from an online Seller's listing. There's no text associated with the photo to explain it. Isn't that crimp mangled?

[image: press fittings crimp]

Comment: Just a guess(probably a bad one) but maybe they only show the good side.  Imagine fitting does need a crimp to seal and a crimp usually deforms.